# Generic field accessor powered by Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to implement a convenient generic field accessor based on `LabelledGeneric`.
The usage should look like:

```
case class Foo(aha: String, uhu: Double, ehe: Int)
case class Bar(uhu: Double, ahu: Boolean)

val foo: Foo = ???
val bar: Bar = ???

val uhuGenField = new GenField('uhu)
val uhuFooAccess = uhuGenField.from[Foo]
val uhuBarAccess = uhuGenField.from[Bar]

def someFunWithUhu[X](xs: Seq[X], access: uhuGenField.Access[X]) = ???
```

I spent some time trying to figure out how to achieve such behaviour.
Eventually I came up with this approach:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.record.Selector

final class GenField[V](val fieldName: Symbol) {
  val fieldWitness = Witness(fieldName)
  type FieldNameType = fieldWitness.T

  trait Access[C] {
    def get(c: C): V
  }

  def from[C](implicit lg2hl: LGtoHL[C]): Access[C] = new Access[C] {
    override def get(c: C): V = {
      val labelledGeneric = lg2hl.labelledGeneric
      val selector = Selector.mkSelector[labelledGeneric.Repr, FieldNameType, V]
      selector(labelledGeneric.to(c))
    }
  }
}

// I need something like this to enable syntax like
//   genField.from[DesiredClass]
// i.e. to "latch" Repr inside a single instance
// and to don't pass it explicitly to `from` method. 
sealed trait LGtoHL[A] {
  type Repr <: HList
  val labelledGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr]
}

object LGtoHL {
  implicit def mkLGtoHL[A, ARepr <: HList](implicit lg: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, ARepr]): LGtoHL[A] = {
    new LGtoHL[A] {
      override type Repr = ARepr
      override val labelledGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr] = lg
    }
  }
}
```

From my prospective this solution should be OK, but it still doesn't work.
The compilation fails with the following error message:

```
Error:(17, 41) lg2hl.Repr is not an HList type
        val selector = Selector.mkSelector[labelledGeneric.Repr, FieldNameType, V]
```

Why does it complain `lg2hl.Repr is not an HList type`?
`Repr` is explicitly defined in `LGtoHL` as `type Repr <: HList`.
What is wrong with my code?

Very appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why are [lenses](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#boilerplate-free-lenses-for-arbitrary-case-classes) not enough?

```
import shapeless.{Lens, lens}

case class Foo(aha: String, uhu: Double, ehe: Int)
case class Bar(uhu: Double, ahu: Boolean)

val foo: Foo = Foo("a", 1.0, 2)
val bar: Bar = Bar(3.0, true)

val fooUhu: Lens[Foo, Double] = lens[Foo] >> 'uhu
val barUhu: Lens[Bar, Double] = lens[Bar] >> 'uhu

fooUhu.get(foo) // 1.0
barUhu.get(bar) // 3.0
```

---

The error message

> `lg2hl.Repr` is not an `HList` type

comes from here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L511

`u.baseType(HConsSym)` is now [NoType](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L1339).

I guess `GenField[V](val fieldName: Symbol)` will not work since `fieldName` in `Witness(fieldName)` must be known at compile time. For example

```
lens[Foo] >> 'uhu
```

works but

```
val uhu: Witness.`'uhu`.T = 'uhu.narrow
lens[Foo] >> uhu
```

doesn't. This is the reason why lenses, Witness, LabelledGeneric are implemented via macros.